# Ruby on rails: button to trigger another action of the same controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller class (personsController), with three actions: new, list and show. The list action shows all the persons (taken from the database). The show action shows a single person. This is my routes.rb file:

```
People::Application.routes.draw do
  get "persons/new"
  get "persons/list"
  root "persons#new"
  resources :persons
end
```

And the output of `rake routes`:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
 persons_new GET    /persons/new(.:format)      persons#new
persons_list GET    /persons/list(.:format)     persons#list
        root GET    /                           persons#new
     persons GET    /persons(.:format)          persons#index
             POST   /persons(.:format)          persons#create
  new_person GET    /persons/new(.:format)      persons#new
 edit_person GET    /persons/:id/edit(.:format) persons#edit
      person GET    /persons/:id(.:format)      persons#show
             PATCH  /persons/:id(.:format)      persons#update
             PUT    /persons/:id(.:format)      persons#update
             DELETE /persons/:id(.:format)      persons#destroy
```

Now from a page like `persons/18` (page: persons/show with id=18), I would like to add a button that redirects to the list page:

```
<%= button_to "List All", :action => "list" %>
```

The problem is that there isn't a route to `persons/18/show_all`, but I would redirect to persons/list. Should I modify the routes.rb file (if yes, how?) or there's a way to "tell to the button" exactly where it should redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the use case of button.

Just use a plain link

```
link_to "List all", persons_list_path
```

You can always decorate the link to whatever style say like a button.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `link_to` and the `persons_list_path` helper, instead of `:action => "list"`:

```
<%= link_to "List All", persons_list_path %>
```